# want to use alphabets instead of integers in the code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have got this code for a puzzle game but i want to use alphabets instaed of integers. I dont want to use numbers in my game but alphabets. everytime i change the text in the button to alphabets, it breaks due to the code. Can anyone tell me how to make the following code work with alphabets.
the java code for the game is;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Level1Activity extends Activity {

    private TextView moveCounter;
    private TextView feedbackText;
    private Button[] buttons;
    private Boolean bad_move=false;
    private static final Integer[] goal = new Integer[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    private ArrayList<Integer> cells = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1_activty);
        buttons=findButtons();

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            this.cells.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(this.cells); //random cells array

        fill_grid();


        moveCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoveCounter);
        feedbackText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FeedbackText);

        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    makeMove((Button) v);
                }
            });
        }


        moveCounter.setText("0");
        feedbackText.setText(R.string.game_feedback_text);

    }
    public Button[] findButtons() {
        Button[] b = new Button[9];

        b[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button00);
        b[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        b[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        b[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
        b[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
        b[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
        b[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
        b[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
        return b;
    }

    public void makeMove(final Button b) {
        bad_move=true;
        int b_text,b_pos,zuk_pos;
        b_text=Integer.parseInt((String) b.getText());
        b_pos=find_pos(b_text);
        zuk_pos=find_pos(0);
        switch(zuk_pos)
        {
            case(0):
                if(b_pos==1||b_pos==3)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(1):
                if(b_pos==0||b_pos==2||b_pos==4)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(2):
                if(b_pos==1||b_pos==5)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(3):
                if(b_pos==0||b_pos==4||b_pos==6)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(4):
                if(b_pos==1||b_pos==3||b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(5):
                if(b_pos==2||b_pos==4||b_pos==8)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(6):
                if(b_pos==3||b_pos==7)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(7):
                if(b_pos==4||b_pos==6||b_pos==8)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
            case(8):
                if(b_pos==5||b_pos==7)
                    bad_move=false;
                break;
        }

        if(bad_move==true)
        {
            feedbackText.setText("Move Not Allowed");
            return;
        }
        feedbackText.setText("Move OK");
        cells.remove(b_pos);
        cells.add(b_pos, 0);
        cells.remove(zuk_pos);
        cells.add(zuk_pos,b_text);


        fill_grid();
        moveCounter.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt((String) moveCounter.getText())+1));

        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(cells.get(i)!=goal[i])
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        feedbackText.setText("we have a winner");
    }

    public void fill_grid()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            int text=cells.get(i);
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams =
                    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)buttons[text].getLayoutParams();
            switch(i)
            {case(0):

                absParams.x = 5;
                absParams.y = 5;
                buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                break;
                case(1):

                    absParams.x = 110;
                    absParams.y = 5;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(2):

                    absParams.x = 215;
                    absParams.y = 5;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(3):

                    absParams.x = 5;
                    absParams.y = 110;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(4):

                    absParams.x =110;
                    absParams.y =110;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(5):

                    absParams.x = 215;
                    absParams.y =110;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(6):

                    absParams.x = 5;
                    absParams.y = 215;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(7):

                    absParams.x = 110;
                    absParams.y = 215;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;
                case(8):

                    absParams.x = 215;
                    absParams.y = 215;
                    buttons[text].setLayoutParams(absParams);
                    break;


            }


        }

    }

    public int find_pos(int element)
    {
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(cells.get(i)==element)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

while the xml file is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Game">


        <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/GameField" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button00" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="5px" android:layout_y="5px" android:text="0" android:textSize="48px" android:background="#000"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="110px" android:layout_y="5px" android:text="D" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="215px" android:layout_y="5px" android:text="3" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="5px" android:layout_y="110px" android:text="B" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="110px" android:layout_y="110px" android:text="6" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="215px" android:layout_y="110px" android:text="5" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="5px" android:layout_y="215px" android:text="4" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button07" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="110px" android:layout_y="215px" android:text="1" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button08" android:layout_height="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:layout_x="215px" android:layout_y="215px" android:text="2" android:textSize="48px"></Button>
        </AbsoluteLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MoveText"
        android:textSize="28px"
        android:text="@string/moves_title">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MoveText"
        android:id="@+id/FeedbackTitleText"
        android:text="@string/feedback_title"
        android:textSize="28px">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MoveText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MoveCounter"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="28px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MoveText">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28px"
        android:id="@+id/FeedbackText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GameField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FeedbackTitleText"
        android:text="@string/game_feedback_text">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `String`. `private static final String[] goal = new String[] {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};`

Comment: @Blundell this would cause problems `cells.get(i)!=goal[i]` as 'cells` is a `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: change cells to `ArrayList<String>` ... literally do this and follow the errors one by one. Come back when you have a problem.

Comment: @Blundell i tried creating an Array of String but then all the integers down in the code creates problem plus even in the array, it says incompatible type for type int. Can you explain in bit more details what to do?

Comment: just follow the errrors, where you add integers to the array and strings instead.